# xml parsing gone wrong, having problem in correct Xpath and loop logic

Tags: python, xpath, xml-parsing

i am using ElementTree xml API to convert some data from local XML file saved in directory, to a CSV file,the XML file looks like this

```
    <object>
        <name>Eosinophil</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>415</xmin>
            <ymin>120</ymin>
            <xmax>532</xmax>
            <ymax>252</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
```

i am trying this python code to do this:

```
def parseXML(xmlfile): 

    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile) 
    root = tree.getroot() 
    mainlist = [] 

    for object in root.findall('.//object'):  
        records = {} 
        for bndbox in object: 
            records[bndbox.tag] = bndbox.text.encode('utf8') 
        mainlist.append(records) 
    return mainlist 

def savetoCSV(newsitems, filename): 

    fields = ['name', 'pose', 'truncated', 'difficult', 'xmin','ymin', 'xmax','ymax'] 

    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fields) 
    writer.writeheader() 
    writer.writerows(newsitems)
```

giving no error but its just creating empty CSV file, with proper headers, since i am new to these things, i searched on resources, and i think there is problem in " object in root.findall" loop, please help in this case.

i am calling these functions as below

```
def main(): 
    newsitems = parseXML('My photo - 09-04-2019_10-11-32.xml') 
    savetoCSV(mainlist, 'sample.csv')
```

can you suggest changes in Xpath involved in the loop, along with loop logic

Comment: Where do you call these functions?

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino sir, see the new edit

Comment: `mainlist` that you pass to `savetoCSV()` doesn't exist in that scope.  change it to `savetoCSV(newsitems, 'sample.csv')`

Comment: You're returning from parseXML and receiving the return as "newitems". But when you call savetoCSV, you call it with "mainlist". You need to change savetoCSV(mainlist, 'sample.csv') to savetoCSV(newitems, 'sample.csv')

Comment: @WillardSolutions and Gabriel, even after doing that, it is giving error : ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'bndbox'

Comment: OK, that error is pretty self explanatory. Add `bndbox` to your list of fields

Comment: @WillardSolutions i tried it, and actually it is not adding xmin and other sub nodes data of bnbbox,  and since bndbox is just a parent node, who itself don't have data, but have subnodes , shouldnt be added as field  ( according to me ).

Comment: Correct, your code doesn't add all those fields in your fieldlist.  You need to loop over all the child nodes of `bndbox` if you want to add those as well.  And If you want to remove the `bndbox` column, you need to explicitly change your code to do that

Comment: @WillardSolutions exactly, then can you suggest me these changes about the correct Xpath which should be used along with correct loop logic

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino i maded those changes but still not adding any data to CSV file, so can you help me suggesting correct Xpath and loop logic for adding node's children data in csv file

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues in your script.

1) you should not use `bndbox` as your for loop object, as there is a node with that name

2) when you are getting the name `bndbox` which has child nodes you should iterate through child nodes to get information.

Here is the solution for your question. (Tested and working as expected)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

def parseXML(xmlfile):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    mainlist = []

    for object in root.findall('.//object'):
        records = {}
        for node in object:

            if (len(node.findall("*"))>0):
                for subnode in node.findall('*'):
                    records[subnode.tag] = subnode.text.encode('utf8')
            else:
                records[node.tag] = node.text.encode('utf8')

        mainlist.append(records)
    print(mainlist)
    return mainlist

def savetoCSV(newsitems, filename):
    fields = ['name', 'pose', 'truncated', 'difficult', 'xmin','ymin', 'xmax','ymax']
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(newsitems)

xmlfile = r"C:\Users\supputuri\PycharmProjects\Selenium_Test\Data\emps.xml"
items = parseXML(xmlfile)
savetoCSV(items,"output.csv")
```

I just added second object set to make sure the script working fine with multiple sets. Here is the snapshot of the output.csv
[image]

Comment: really thanks a lot mate, but still i didn't get that why we are using if and else condition, can you brief about that